# ActiveAndroid: lock records for updates?

Tags: android, activerecord, android-sqlite, activeandroid

In ActiveRecord, there's a concept of [locking records](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update) for updates to ensure that a stale object doesn't get saved to the database.

Is there equivalent functionality in ActiveAndroid? If so, is there a link showing how to do it? If not, what would be the best approach to prevent stale objects from getting saved to the db?

Comment: Do you mean not saving duplicates?

Comment: Not exactly. Let's say you query an object, A = Foo(1), and then you query B = Foo(1). You now have two objects (A & B)  representing the record with id=1. Now, if you modify A then save, B will now become stale because it doesn't have the latest changes that were made to A.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAndroid has a concept of `beginTransaction() and endTransaction()` which basically are similar to the `locking record` concept in `activeRecord`. By using the `beginTransaction()` you ensure that while any changes being made to a method or data is being accessed, no other object can interfere with the process. Once the `endTransaction()` is executed, the method is "unlocked" and other objects can start to interact with it.

Comment: transactions serve a different purpose. A transaction is usually used to batch updates/inserts/deletes so that either all succeed or all fail. It also improves performance of these operations. It will not prevent the update of a stale object.

Comment: Pardon me if i am wrong here since i am learning to use ActiveAndroid myself, but as far as my knowledge activeAndroid maps up to SQLite which on its own does the locking of the database while reading,writing etc...

Comment: yes, that's correct; but again, as far as I know, you can still update with stale data.

Comment: On ActiveAndroid? No. I have tried it. And it wont let you access a data while its inProgress. So the other object has to wait

Comment: I understand what you mean. Let me explain more. Assume you have A = Foo(1) and B = Foo(1). Modify A and then save A in a transaction. Now, after the transaction is over, evaluate B. Does B have the updates that were made to A? What happens when you save B? Will saving B override the changes that A made? The point here isn't concurrent access to the DB. I understand  what db locking does, the point here is that B has an old copy of the record. In ActiveRecord, depending on the chosen strategy, you will get an error when you save B because B holds stale data.

Comment: Maybe this comment is late, but if you do find something, please update the answer. I couldn't get any specific detail as of today

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but what I am doing is, declaring an unique field in my model class, and onUniqueConflict  replacing the old record with the new one.

```
    @Column(name = "userId", notNull = true,unique = true,onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE)
    private String userId;
```